# How to stop ( kill ) AsyncTask in android

Tags: android, gridview, asynchronous

Hi I am new to android:

I am displaying image thumbs in GridView. For better performance I am loading it asynchronously.

My AsyncTask is as:

```
class BitmapWorkerTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Bitmap> {
        private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;
        private int data = 0;
        private String image_path;

        public BitmapWorkerTask(ImageView imageView) {
            imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
        }

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(Integer... params) {
            data = params[0];
            Bitmap picture = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image_path);
            int width = picture.getWidth();
            int height = picture.getHeight();
            float aspectRatio = (float) width / (float) height;
            int newWidth = 98;
            int newHeight = (int) (98 / aspectRatio);
            return picture = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(picture, newWidth,
                    newHeight, true);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
            if (imageViewReference != null && bitmap != null) {
                final ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
                if (imageView != null) {
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                }

            }
        }

        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
            this.cancel(true);
        }
    }
```

and Calling form:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        ListRowHolder listRowHolder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.ll_sponsor_list_item,
                    parent, false);
            listRowHolder = new ListRowHolder();
            listRowHolder.imgSponsor = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.imggrid_item_image);
            convertView.setTag(listRowHolder);

        } else {
            listRowHolder = (ListRowHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        try {
            BitmapWorkerTask task = new BitmapWorkerTask(
                    listRowHolder.imgSponsor);
            task.image_path = ImageName.get(position);
            task.execute(1);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(ctx, e + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        return convertView;
    }
```

The  problem here is the tasks are running in background even I clicked on back button.

Comment: You can try `cancel(true)` not guaranteed to work always. Also if you call this, be ready to catch interrupt exceptions in  `doInBackground`.

Answer (score 15):

Use [`cancel()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#cancel(boolean)) to stop a `AsyncTask`:

```
task.cancel(true);
```

The [documentation of AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) provides some additional details in the 'Cancelling a task' section:

> A task can be cancelled at any time by invoking [cancel(boolean)](/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#cancel(boolean)). Invoking
>    this method will cause subsequent calls to [isCancelled()](/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#isCancelled()) to return true.
>    After invoking this method, [onCancelled(Object)](/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onCancelled(Result)), instead of
>    [onPostExecute(Object)](/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute(Result)) will be invoked after [doInBackground(Object[])](/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#doInBackground(Params...)) returns. To ensure that a task is cancelled as quickly as possible, you should always check the return value of [isCancelled()](/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#isCancelled()) periodically from [doInBackground(Object[])](/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#doInBackground(Params...)), if possible (inside a loop for instance.)

Answer (score 5):

First, you need to keep references to every asynctask you execute. When the activity pauses, you should iterate through the references to the asynctask and cancel them with [cancel()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#cancel%28boolean%29). You should also call [get()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get%28%29) on each of the asynctasks. This will make sure that the UI thread waits until the asynctask is finished before changing activities.

Use cancel(true) if you want the asynctask's thread to be interrupted, or use cancel(false), and at points in your doInBackground() method you should check [isCancelled()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#isCancelled%28%29) and return.

For safety you must be very careful with asynctasks. Check out [this article](http://www.shanekirk.com/2012/04/asynctask-missteps/) on safely handling them.

Answer (score 0):

Make something like this

```
private class myAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {
          private boolean isTaskCancelled = false;

          public void cancelTask(){
               isTaskCancelled = true;
          }

          private boolean isTaskCancelled(){
               return isTaskCancelled;
          }

          protected Void doInBackground( Void... ignoredParams ) {
            //Do some stuff
             if (isTaskCancelled()){
                return;
             }
          }


          protected void onPostExecute( Void array )
          {
           //Do something
          }



          protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values)
          {
           //Do something
          }
    }
```

When you press back on the Activity, put the asynctask in cancelled mode, so it will stop executing things.

**Check for the cancelled method in every step you make in your asynctask, to stop it on the next line**

Comment: There is a isCancelled() method and cancel() method in asynctask already. There is no reason to implement your own

Comment: If you use your own you will have more control, its like CANCEL method on Thread, it will stop, but the better way to finish that thread is check for your cancelled on the critic parts of the algorithm

Comment: That's what is implemented in asynctask for you. You call cancel(false) if you want control over cancellation, then in your algorithm you just check isCancelled(). It's exactly what you implemented.